# Can an aggregation have two keys in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, nest

Suppose I have an index with a nested document that looks like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "assignment": {
      "properties":{
        "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "typeOfLoss":{
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lineItems": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "categoryCode":{
            "type": "string"
          },
          "selectorCode":{
            "type": "string"
          },
          "roomType": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
}
```

I now want to get a count aggregation of "lineItems" documents that returns the selectorCode and categoryCode where the roomType matches a search query. I am new to elasticsearch and can write my query in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as theCount, ln.category_code, ln.selector_code
FROM line_items as ln, assignment
WHERE assignment.location = "84043"
AND assignment.typeOfLoss = "Fire"
AND ln.roomType = "kitchen"
GROUP BY ln.category_code, ln.selector_code
ORDER BY theCount DESC;
```

I have started on the NEST query but am having some problems and am hoping someone can point me in the right directions.

```
var typeOfLossQuery = new TermQuery
{
  Field = "typeOfLoss",
  Value = typeOfLoss
};

var locationQuery = new TermQuery
{
  Field = "location",
  Value = location
};

var roomTypeQuery = new TermQuery
{
  Field = "roomType",
  Value = roomType
};

var result = client.Search<LineItem>(s => s
  .From(0)
  .Size(numberOfItems)
  .Query(q => q.HasParent<Assignment>(a => a
    .Query(x =>x
      .MatchAll() && typeOfLossQuery && locationQuery
    )
  ) && q.MatchAll() && roomTypeQuery
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this with ElasticSearch but it's not quite as clean as in SQL.  We can accomplish this with [Nested Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

## Setup

I'm going to setup the data so that you'd get the following equivalent result in SQL:

categoryCode | selectorCode | Count

c1 | s1 | 1

c1 | s2 | 2

```
PUT test1

PUT test1/_mapping/type1
{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "typeOfLoss": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lineItems": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "categoryCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "selectorCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "roomType": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test1/type1
{
  "location":"l1",
  "lineItems":
    {
      "categoryCode": "c1",
      "selectorCode": "s1",
      "roomType": "r1"
    }
}

POST test1/type1
{
  "location":"l1",
  "lineItems":
    {
      "categoryCode": "c1",
      "selectorCode": "s2",
      "roomType": "r1"
    }
}

POST test1/type1
{
  "location":"l1",
  "lineItems":
    {
      "categoryCode": "c1",
      "selectorCode": "s2",
      "roomType": "r1"
    }
}
```

## Query

```
GET test1/type1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "lineItems",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "lineItems.roomType": {
            "value": "r1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nestedAgg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "lineItems"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byCategory": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "lineItems.categoryCode",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bySelector": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "lineItems.selectorCode",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query is saying the following:

1. only show me data `where roomType = 'r1'`
2. aggregate (group in SQL) by `categoryCode`
3. created a "nested" or "sub" aggregation on "selectorCode"

## Result

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "nestedAgg": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "byCategory": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "c1",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "bySelector": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "s2",
                  "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                  "key": "s1",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the results returns a list of aggregations.  Inside an aggregation is a "bucket".  Notice that the outer bucket for `byCategory` shows a `doc_count` of 3.  That's because there are 3 records that match in the DB.

Then, nested inside that is the `bySelector` bucket showing `s2` and `s1` with a `doc_count` of 2 and 1 respectively.

Hopefully that helps, I'll let you turn all this into a NEST query.

Comment: Thanks for all of the effort! I think this answers my question that you can't have two keys, but doesn't solve my problem. If I had two CategoryCodes: C1 and C2 and inside of C1 I had SelectorCode: S1, S1, S2 and S3, then in C2 I had SelectorCodes: S1, S1, S1. I would want to get C2, S1 as the first item because that pair of CategoryCode and SelectorCode happen the most, but in your example I would get C1, S1 then C1,S2 and then C1,S3 because we group by CategoryCode then by SelectorCode.

Comment: I hear what you're saying.  All the data is there, but you need to do a bit of work to arrange it how you want.  You can't just `ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC`